# make install command throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have tried the following link to mount S3 bucket into EC2 :

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=313009
```

I started typing the following commands :

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/s3fs/s3fs-1.74.tar.gz

tar zxf s3fs-1.74.tar.gz

apt-get install build-essential libxml2-dev libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

sudo make install
```

The next command to type is this :

```
 sudo touch /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74 && sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74 && sudo echo 'Accesskey:SecretKey' > /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74
```

But, when I type this, I get the following response :

```
-bash: /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74: Permission denied
```

I am not root but used sudo.
May I know what's wrong with this??

Comment: are you root when you run the command ?

Comment: I typed **sudo make install** because I'm not root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change directory to `s3fs-1.74` and compile it as follows:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Verify it `which s3fs`

**edit**

To solve dependencies run: `sudo apt-get install fuse libxml2-dev libssl-dev`

To solve the permission issue run;

```
chown user:user /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74
```

Comment: **./configure  --prefix=/usr** returned this error : checking for DEPS... configure: error: Package requirements (fuse >= 2.8.4 libcurl >= 7.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6 libcrypto >= 0.9) were not met:

No package 'libcrypto' found

Comment: @prudhvi install the missing package one by one

Comment: There is a mistake in your edit : it is **libxml2-dev**. Please change. Thank you

Comment: I have modified my question. Please look into it if you have time.

Comment: Use `chown user:user /etc/passwd-s3fs-1.74`